# Serialize a Map<LocalDate, Object> with Ktor and kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

Here's a Ktor route that returns a map of LocalDates:

```
route {
   get {
       val map = mapOf(LocalDate.now() to "test")
       call.respond(map)
   }
}
```

LocalDate is not serializable, however:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Can't locate argument-less serializer for class LocalDate. For generic classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.
```

I've built my own serializer:

```
@Serializer(forClass = LocalDate::class)
object LocalDateSerializer : KSerializer<LocalDate> {
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: LocalDate) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): LocalDate {
        return LocalDate.parse(decoder.decodeString())
    }
}
```

I can use this serializer in a data class, e.g. `data class Foo(@Serializable(with=LocalDateSerializer::class)date: LocalDate`. But I don't know how to get it work with my map.

I've tried a couple different annotations:

```
val map: Map<@ContextualSerialization LocalDate, String> = mapOf(LocalDate.now() to "test")
// OR
val map: Map<@Serializable(with=LocalDateSerializer::class) LocalDate, String> = mapOf(LocalDate.now() to "test")
```

And I've tried registering it with Ktor:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(module = serializersModuleOf(LocalDate::class, LocalDateSerializer))
}
```

No matter what I try, I get the same `SerializationException` as above.

How can I apply my serializer automatically when kotlinx.serialization tries to parse a LocalDate? OR how can I suggest a serializer when Ktor tries to serialize my map?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it seems that this functionality is not supported yet in ktor. I filed an issue: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1879. Feel free to continue discussion there.